# Find Sequences of any range

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, range, sequence

Given an array of numbers, print the each and every range available. 
For example
Array : 9, 3, 5, 7, 4, 8, 1
Output: 1, 3-5, 7-9
Note: Please execute this problem without using an additional array.

How do i proceed?
*

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a[]={9,8,8,7,6,5,14};
int n= sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
int i,j;
int temp;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
         {
               for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
               {
                     if(a[i]>a[j])
                     {
                           temp=a[i];
                           a[i]=a[j];
                           a[j]=temp;
                     }
               }
        }
}
```

*
1st i will sort in ascending order, i don't know what to do next?
P.S : I am coding this in C.

Answer (score 0):

The next step is to identify sequences. Try the following loop (not fully debugged):

```
first= next= a[0];
for (i=1; i<n; i++) {
    if (a[i] > next+1) {
        if (next>first)
             printf("%d-%d,", first, next);
        else printf("%d,", first);
        first= next= a[i];
    }
    else next++;
}
```

Comment: His sorting code might also have a problem.  Looks like he was trying to do a bubble sort.

Comment: You can ask, and show the code of what you have tried. We should only be helping you fixing [thought] errors but not be doing your homework.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple, readable function for you, take a look:

```
void printRange(int sortedArray[], int len) {
    int i, current, next, printStart, printEnd, startIndex = 0;
    bool print = false;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printStart = sortedArray[startIndex];
        printEnd = sortedArray[i];

        current = sortedArray[i];
        if(i < len -1) {
             next = sortedArray[i + 1];
        } else
              next = current;

        if (next - current != 1) {
            startIndex = i + 1;
            print = true;
        }

        if (print) {
            if (printStart - printEnd == 0) {
                printf("%d,", printStart);
            } else {
                printf("%d-%d,", printStart, printEnd);
            }
            print = false;
        }
    }
}
```

[Run live.](http://ideone.com/8knzJm)

Note, for good understanding variable `current` is declared whereas `current` and `printEnd` is same. You may replace `current` by `printEnd`.

Comment: @Akash, its a complete different problem. Open another thread and ask that question. Because its not convenient to give answer in comment.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, it can be, as I don't test it from all possible cases, will you please tell me in which case it will give wrong answer?

Comment: @Akash, I love to give answer in stackoverflow because the community helps me a lot, so if you want answer, you have to communicate with me only via stackoverflow.

Comment: @rakeb.void  For example in this statement  next = sortedArray[i + 1]; you are trying to access memory beyond the array when i is equal to len - 1, are not you?

Comment: @Akash  Sometimes a wrong code can work in some particular cases.:) Nevertheless this function has undefined behaviour and can produce a wrong result.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow yea true, maybe for some outputs it doesnt work

Comment: @rakeb.void  Even the updated function will not work correctly. Consider a situation when the array has only one element.

Comment: Hahahahaha, the OP can handle some basic checking I guess, currently im writing from mobile phone, soon I will check everything and update my code so that OP can submit the code to ACM online judge and got accepted. Ty for your concern.

Answer (score 0):

If you may to change the original array that is if you may to sort it then the program can look like

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int cmp( const void *lhs, const void *rhs )
{
    int a = *( const int * )lhs;
    int b = *( const int * )rhs;

    return ( b < a ) - ( a < b );
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 9, 8, 8, 7, 6, 5, 14 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    qsort( a, N, sizeof( int ), cmp );
/*    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    printf( "\n" );
*/    
    int *p = a;
    int *start = a, *end = a;
    do
    {
        if ( ++p == a + N || *p  != *end + 1 )
        {
            printf( "{ %d", *start );
            start == end ? printf( " }\n" ) : printf( ", %d }\n", *end );
            start = end = p;
        }
        else
        {
            end = p;
        }
    } while ( p != a + N );            
}
```

The program output is

```
{ 5, 8 }
{ 8, 9 }
{ 14 }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84711/discussion-on-answer-by-vlad-from-moscow-find-sequences-of-any-range).

Answer (score 0):

There are already some pretty good answers for this task in here but maybe the sorting part in the beginning is worth to talk a little bit more about. Especially if you need something like that in school, university or in a job interview.

The easiest sorting technique/algorithm would be something like **BubbleSort** which can easily be implemented with 2 *for* loops.

> ```
> void BubbleSort (int a[], int length)
> {
>   int i, j, temp;
>   
>    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
>    {
>        for (j = 0; j < length - i - 1; j++)
>        {
>            if (a[j + 1] < a[j])
>            {
>                temp = a[j];
>                a[j] = a[j + 1];
>                a[j + 1] = temp;
>            }
>        }
>    }
> }
> ```
>
> [Source and more information](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Sorting/Bubble_sort)

The best way of sorting such arrays with integers (or any kind of number) is **QuickSort**. The algorithm is pretty advanced but if you watch a good video on Youtube or read this [article](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Sorting/Quicksort) you definitely know how it works.

> ```
> void quick(int array[], int start, int end){
>    if(start < end){
>        int l=start+1, r=end, p = array[start];
>        while(l<r){
>            if(array[l] <= p)
>                l++;
>            else if(array[r] >= p)
>                r--;
>            else
>                swap(array[l],array[r]);
>        }
>        if(array[l] < p){
>            swap(array[l],array[start]);
>            l--;
>        }
>        else{
>            l--;
>            swap(array[l],array[start]);
>        }
>        quick(array, start, l);
>        quick(array, r, end);
>    }
> }
> ```
>
> [Source and more information](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Sorting/Quicksort)

*Note:* **QuickSort** uses a technique called *recursion*. If you are not familiar which that you can have a look here:

> In computer science, *recursion* is a method of solving a problem where the solution depends on solutions to smaller instances of the same problem. Such problems can generally be solved by iteration, but this needs to identify and index the smaller instances at programming time. *Recursion* solves such recursive problems by using **functions that call themselves** from within their own code. The approach can be applied to many types of problems, and *recursion* is one of the central ideas of computer science.
>
> [Source and more information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science))

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are a great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)